# Android emulator custom rom detection

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator

Im using the Android emulator with Android 5.1.1 API level 22

To test my work it is necessary to install WhatsApp on the emulator.

On my Mac it works just fine, but on Linux I get this message and it won't let me setup WhatsApp.

`You have a custom ROM installed. Custom ROMs can cause problems with WhatsApp Messenger and are unsupported by our customer service team.`

Can anyone tell me why this happens on linux and what I can do to fix it?